# removal of breadcrumb at xwiki in flamingo skin

Tags: xwiki

Hello,

how can i remove the breadcrum from flamingo skin at xwiki??? and how can i 
   add css styles to the existing page. i tried adding

```
    1)style
    2)xhtmlxsl
    3)fopxsl
```

as text area in pdfclass and then adding it as an object in the page i want.
        adding css style

```
  .breadcrumb {
        display:none;
        } 


from this site http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/AdminGuide/Configuration#HTurningoffcommentsorattachments
```

did not help.

any suggestions!!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to add styling to an XWiki page you need to use a StyleSheetExtension (SSX) object. Use ?editor=objects for your page. Read more at http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/DevGuide/SkinExtensionsTutorial and http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Skin%20Extension%20Plugin

Style tag can also be used, but inside a {{html}} macro.

Not really sure why you mentioned the configuration page, or why you mentioned the pdfclass. Hope it helps.